# Using WAN in a private network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I had a look at two of our access point settings. I found something which was a bit confusing to me.

Instead of giving the router used as an access point a static IP from the same main router subnet, they set the LAN with a different private IP range, enabled DHCP, and at the WAN settings they set the main IP range basically like a home router and ISP router scenario.

Please explain why it was done that way and what are the pros and cons of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I get from your question is there are two devices, One is the main router and there is a second router which can be used as an access point/repeater/router/bridge. You are saying following is happening in your setup.

`ISP------WAN:MAIN ROUTER:LAN------WAN:SECOND ROUTER:LAN---YOUR CLIENTS`

> Why It Was Done that way , an what are the Cons and Pros of this
>   method

Well there are multiple interpretations of how the second router can be used. It can be used as an access point(as you said), as a router(as they are using), as a bridge, as a repeater.

Pros and Cons of using it as a router:

**Cons:**

- Setup is a little complex.
- Clients connected to second router will be NATed twice, once at the main router then at the second router.
- Manage both routers(as anything going wrong will have to be checked on both)

**Pros:**

- You get two pools from DHCP to use so your IPs are increased(without actually increasing the broadcast domain on first)
- Wireless clients from second access point don't have to go all the way to the main router to communicate with another client which connected on the same access point(clients will be locally switched).
- Delegation of user base(you can have a different LAN for these users, hence an isolated network for them. Which is very much needful in guests)

Hope this helps!

Comment: For your Pros, you can have two sets of DHCP without using NAT. You can use a router as a router to route between networks, and routers don't require NAT to function, although most consumer-grade devices default to that. Clients on a WAP do not need to go back through the first router to communicate if they are on the same LAN; the WAP will locally switch traffic between the hosts. Guests connected to the second router will still have access to the devices on the main router.

Comment: About NAT, you can use router to route packets but the main router won't NAT the subnet coming from the second router. In case of WAP only you can switch packets locally but not in bridge mode or repeater mode.

Comment: In bridged mode, it acts as a bridge, and it will switch frames locally. That is the very definition of a bridge. A bridge will learn which MAC addresses are connected to which ports, and it will switch the frames based on that. You can set up some consumer-grade routers to route multiple networks. All the consumer-grade routers I ever owned (from various manufacturers) support the RIP routing protocol. It is pretty simple to configure that.

Comment: Correcting myself in case of bridge it would switch packets locally.

Comment: I was just looking at some of the home routers (Linksys, Netgear, D-Link, etc.) that I have collected over the years. All of them support RIP, and most support static routing entries.

Comment: Yes but in the end what is needed is NATing the LAN IPs of downstream router with ISPs given WAN IP that won't happen if you route the segment on the main router and not use NAT on second router.

Comment: That has always worked for me.

Comment: Well you are more experienced, So can't argue with that. Though I have to check and I don't have a setup to do that.

Comment: Any way , I'm changing this scenario , I don't like users to hide over a single IP address , I have to Keep them traced , report their bandwidth usage "Company Policy" , thanks guys.